# Count All Occurences of SKU in Sales Orders

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table that stores sales orders in the following manner:

```
order_id | sku_1  | sku_2  | order_date
-------------------------------------
1        | FC-123 | FC-597 | 2016-10-23
2        | FC-097 | FC-123 | 2016-10-23
3        | FC-123 | FC-123 | 2016-10-23
```

I would like to calculate how many of a particular SKU are sold per day.  As you can see, a SKU can be present more than once per sales order, which is giving me trouble.

I have tried counting the number of rows in which the SKU is present, but this will obviously come up short in the event that the SKU is present multiple times on one order.

Could anyone please help?  I'm sure there's a solution for this.  The actual table is much more complex, but I believe this example should illustrate what I'm having difficulty with.

Thanks!

Comment: can you also post your query?

Comment: You should split the tables into an order table and an orderItems table

Comment: What do you do for orders with more than 2 items?

Comment: @baao that's probably a wise idea.  We'll refactor at some point in the future.

Barmar - our sales orders have a maximum set of possible SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT order_date,COUNT( sku ) AS count_of_skus_per_order_day
  FROM
     (
       SELECT order_date,sku_1 AS sku
         FROM sales_orders
         UNION 
       SELECT order_date,sku_2 AS sku
         FROM sales_orders
      ) z;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking in each column?  Here is a "tricky" way to do the sum:

```
select count(*) + sum(case when sku_1 = sku_2 then 1 else 0 end)
from orders o
where 'FC-123' in (sku_1, sku_2) and
      order_date = $date;
```

A somewhat more verbose method is:

```
select (sum(case when sku_1 = 'FC-123' then 1 else 0 end) +
        sum(case when sku_2 = 'FC-123' then 1 else 0 end)
       )
from orders o
where 'FC-123' in (sku_1, sku_2) and
      order_date = $date;
```